# Как сделать ограничение на отправку сообщений в 1 секунду?

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Пишу  телеграмм бота на python. Если пользователь присылает много сообщений, то бот начинает выдавать результаты хаотично. Как сделать задержку сообщений в 1 секунду?